# match element name in web.config transformation

Tags: asp.net, deployment, web-config, web-deployment

I am trying to match element by element name, I have to change sessionState element timeout in release, but I cannot match it by any attribute value.

```
<sessionState timeout="5000"/>
```

How can I match this element in Web.Release.config?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

this should work:

```
<sessionState timeout="2000" 
 xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(timeout)">
</sessionState>
```

Comment: Beautiful solution. Just what I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 4):

In case there are those that would like to change all attributes here it is

```
<sessionState xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="XPath(/configuration/system.web/sessionState)" 
                mode="SQLServer"
                stateConnectionString="tcpip=1234.00" 
                sqlConnectionString="myConnection"
                cookieless="false" 
                timeout="2000"  />
```